# How to solve one errror installing an Angular Template ngx-admin

Tags: html, angular, typescript, web, frontend

I want to use ngx-admin template for my project, I followed the instructions to install into angular 14 and I get these errors

```
  npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.       
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ngx-admin@8.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^12.2.16" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^10.0.4" from ng2-ckeditor@1.2.9
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\HP Spectre X360 G1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP Spectre X360 G1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-23T03_56_45_643Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\dev\Angular\proyectos\09-ngx-admin>
```

Comment: `ngx-admin` doesn't support Angular v14 yet, refer to https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin

Comment: Oops! There is a free template that can works with Angular 14 like ngx-admin ?